# rewriting equation for optimization to matrix equation

Tags: optimization, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, least-squares

I need to minimize the equation in the attached picture.

Given a function p=f(q). p are integers ranging from 1 to 254, while q is a set of 254 real numbers. f is a monotonic function that maps a member from set q to set p. n is the number of pixels in an image, while a, b and c refer to three different images. Now I need to find the inverse of f, or simply the 244 real numbers in q (since f is just a function for integers) in which q[i] = f_inverse(p[i]) (assume p is arranged from 1 to 254 in order).

My approach is to write p as an nx3 array, where the nth row contains the three elements pa(n),pa(n), pb(n). This array can be constructed easily from the three images that each contain n pixels. Then I have the following code:

```
def g(q,p):
    n = p.shape[0]
    value = 0
    for i in range(n):
        value = value + (q[p[i,0]+q[p[i,1]-q[p[i,2]])**2
    return value
guess = np.arange(0,256)/255.0
q = spo.minimize(g,guess,args=p)
```

And then I try to minimize function g to try to get the vector q. However, it says 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,254) (87500,3)'. These are the shapes of q (the unknown to be solved) and the p (87500 is the number of pixs) respectively. Why is that?

Besides, even if it works, it seems like a very slow method as I am trying to optimize a function with 244 untry to get a solution that consists of 254 unknowns simultaneously. The equation I'm trying to solve is actually from a research paper, and that paper mentions something rewriting the equation into Aq=0, then using singular value decomposition to obtain the solution. I have no idea what the whole paragraph means, so I'm wondering if there are any ways to rewrite the problem into something that can be handled more easily and efficiently.

[image]

Comment: It became not clear to me what variables are given and which variables are  the unknowns in relation to Eq. (4). A reference to the paper or a small dataset would also make it easier to help with the problem

Comment: it's equation (4) in this paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1421735

Comment: p are the pixel values which are known. p=f(q), and the aim is to find q

Comment: I finally got around to browsing through the paper: The way I understand it, you want to find the function *f^{-1}(q)*. In the paper *f^{-1}(q)* is parametrized by a histogram. Eq. (4) and (5) are utilizing  the constraint *q_a + q_b = q_c* to reduce the number of solutions.